# what's different between two code in directx11?

Tags: draw, directx-11, vertex-buffer

i want to display a box by directx11, and when i try two code which i think both is same occur different result. what's different these two code??

code start from this phrase.

```
std::vector<VERTEX::objVertex> vertices;

HRESULT Object::Create(ID3D11Device* pDevice, const char* Filename)
{
vector<UINT> Indices;

wchar_t* strFilename = new wchar_t[MAX_PATH];
mbstowcs(strFilename, Filename, strlen(Filename) + 1);

HR(LoadGeometryFromOBJ(strFilename, &Indices));
HR(CreateBuffer(pDevice, &Indices));

return S_OK;
}
```

different start from these codes.

first type code.

```
HRESULT Object::LoadGeometryFromOBJ(const WCHAR* strFilename, vector<UINT>* Indices)
{
vector<XMFLOAT3> Positions;
vector<XMFLOAT2> TexCoords;
vector<XMFLOAT3> Normals;

VERTEX::objVertex vertic[] =
{
{ XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
{ XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
{ XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
{ XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
{ XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
{ XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
{ XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
{ XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) }
};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
vertices.push_back(vertic[i]);
}

UINT indic[] = {
// front face
0, 1, 2,
0, 2, 3,

// back face
4, 6, 5,
4, 7, 6,

// left face
4, 5, 1,
4, 1, 0,

// right face
3, 2, 6,
3, 6, 7,

// top face
1, 5, 6,
1, 6, 2,

// bottom face
4, 0, 3,
4, 3, 7
};

for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
Indices->push_back(indic[i]);

return S_OK;
}

HRESULT Object::CreateBuffer(ID3D11Device* Device, vector<UINT>* indices)
{
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX::objVertex)* 8;
vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
vinitData.pSysMem = &(vertices[0]);
HR(Device->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &pmVB));


// Create the index buffer



D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT)* 36;
ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
ibd.StructureByteStride = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
iinitData.pSysMem = &((*indices)[0]);
HR(Device->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &pmIB));

return S_OK;
}
```

second type code.

```
HRESULT Object::CreateBuffer(ID3D11Device* Device, vector<UINT>* index)
{
VERTEX::objVertex vertices[] =
{
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) }
};

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX::objVertex)* 8;
vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
vinitData.pSysMem = vertices;
HR(Device->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &pmVB));


// Create the index buffer

UINT indices[] = {
    // front face
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,

    // back face
    4, 6, 5,
    4, 7, 6,

    // left face
    4, 5, 1,
    4, 1, 0,

    // right face
    3, 2, 6,
    3, 6, 7,

    // top face
    1, 5, 6,
    1, 6, 2,

    // bottom face
    4, 0, 3,
    4, 3, 7
};

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT)* 36;
ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
ibd.StructureByteStride = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
iinitData.pSysMem = indices;
HR(Device->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &pmIB));

return S_OK;
}
```

for me these two code looks like just same. i think first code just spread from second code to two phrase, and set vertex data by vector type. but first code didn't work.

what's different these two code, and if i want to write first type what should i do??

Comment: Likely there's a difference in assumption about triangle-winding order, and one version is simply back-face culling. You didn't provide your render code or state object setup, so it's all conjecture since you haven't even described what 'code didn't' work' means. BTW, if you are completely new to Direct3D 11, you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).

Comment: First step of Direct3D debugging: enable the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) and look for diagnostic messages, and make sure that you are checking anything that returns an ``HRESULT`` for failure.

Comment: i mean that code didn't work is box didn't display just display only context. else rendering settings are all same.

Comment: In your ``D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC`` state object creation, try changing ``CullMode`` to ``D3D11_CULL_NONE``

Comment: no it didn't work, it's just same before

Comment: sorry. camera was looking at little different position...